# c++ getline() with structs

Tags: c++, struct, getline

```
struct car
{
  string name;
  int year;
};    

int main() {
    int noOfCars;
    cout<<"enter no_ of cars : ";    
    cin>>noOfCars;    
    car* cars = new car[noOfCars];    
    for(int i=0;i<noOfCars;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Car #"<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"Name : ";    
        getline(cin,(cars[i].name));  //here is the problem 
        cout<<"\n year : ";    
        cin>>cars[i].year;    
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

something wron with taking a whole line as a string input to the name in the strcut,doesn't even take any thing and proceeds to ge the year directly ... :S ???

it works with cin,but i want to take a whole line !
and it works with strings globally defined,but not with this inside the struct

Comment: `cin>>noOfCars;` There's your problem. I challenge you to find one of the many dupes explaining why. I've found about 4 in the related questions list.

Comment: @chris Could you give a hint, I don't see a problem with this line?

Comment: @ChristianRau, Think about the state of the input stream through all of this.

Comment: does it buffer the newline so  it makes an error ?

Comment: @user1609974, Exactly, the newline is not discarded after `cin >>` because it reads what it needs to. `getline` reads until the first newline. If you didn't see it mentioned, I point you to [`cin.ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: between formatted and unformatted input, the delimiter gets into the stream.
you can simply use ignore.
its been over the forum for quite some time.

Comment: @CodingMash, `clear()` clears flags.

Comment: `clear()` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: btw is there another way to flush the stream?

Comment: `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` does the trick I think, but I always have to look these things up.

Comment: It does it fine..
i have always worked with it.
but maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: @CodingMash, `cin.sync()` has a possibility of clearing the stream, but the behaviour isn't guaranteed, so your code won't be totally portable.

Comment: don't mix `operator>>` and `std::getline()` when reading user input. Use one or the other but not both. Its not that it can't be done but that it makes things very complex when you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert  `cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );` after `getline` .

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct car
{
  string name;
  int year;
};    

int main() {
    int noOfCars;
    cout<<"enter no_ of cars : ";    
    cin>>noOfCars;    
    car* cars = new car[noOfCars];    
    for(int i=0;i<noOfCars;i++)
    {
        cin.clear();


        cout<<"Car #"<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"Name : ";    
        getline(cin,(cars[i].name));  //here is the problem 

     cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );

        cout<<"\n year : ";    
        cin>>cars[i].year;    
        cout<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been explained so many times as chris says.

The problem is in your preceding input call

```
cin>>noOfCars;
```

This reads a number, i.e. it reads digits, it does not read a newline. You might type a newline but that doesn't mean that it gets read. In fact the newline is left over until the next time you read, which is your `getline` call. So your first `getline` call reading the newline that has been left over from when you read the number of cars.

It doesn't surprise me that newbies get this wrong, but it does indicate that you should spent some time researching your problem before asking a question. This has been asked and answered hundreds of times before.

Comment: On the ohter hand, it's _really_ hard to search for.

Comment: @MooingDuck, True, my comment went off of this question's related list.

Comment: Well, that's a fair point too :D  You're right.  Apperently it is findable.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Ironic, in order to find the dupe, you have to ask the question ;) Searching what you would have put as a title might net the same results, though. I'm not sure how the related list works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin>>noOfCars` leaves the newline generated by the Enter key in the input queue. The `getline(cin,(cars[i].name))` is simply reading that newline character and assigns a null string to the `car[i].name` array. And since at the end of your loop `cin>>cars[i].year` does the same thing over and over, `getline(cin,(cars[i].name))` is always reading a newline character before it lets you input anything.

To fix this you just need to discard the newlines character after `cin` reads `noOfCars` and `cars[i].year`, which can be cleanly done by concatenating a `cin.get()` after your `cin`s like this:

```
cout<<"enter no_ of cars : ";    
(cin>>noOfCars).get();            //here is the solution
car* cars = new car[noOfCars];    
for(int i=0;i<noOfCars;i++)
{
    cout<<"Car #"<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"Name : ";    
    getline(cin,(cars[i].name));  //here is the problem 
    cout<<"\n year : ";    
    (cin>>cars[i].year).get();   //here is the solution 
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 
    `cin.getline(Cars[i].name,streamsize);` 
Where streamsize is the maximum size of the string. I think that's the simplest form.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the problem. It won't compile, and even when the error is fixed it will fail in the same way that the OP's code fails.

Comment: getline() works with string object, not cin.getline() The other answer pointed it out wrongly as well..